# Extracting Archive Files in Java

Tags: java, extract, archive

I am looking for a library to extract archive files with. For example, zips, rars, tars, wars, ...

My application so far only supports .ZIP's & .RAR's, but I want to increase support for several other archive types. Not only that, but I want the library to "detect" archive files, even if I give them another extension or no extension at all.

Basically, I'm looking for some sort of interface to which I can pass a file and path, which then checks if the file is an archive file, returns an error if it's not, and extracts the files to the specified path if it is. I'm guessing that there are different implementations for different filetypes, but it would be very useful if the library detects this, and automatically passes it on to the right implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/).

This library is also used by the great [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) which can be used to detect different file formats also with no extension (but maybe the huge Apache Tika is an overkill for your task).

Comment: Inside these archives resides a complex directory structure. How would I go about writing an ArchiveInputStream, containing this structure and its files, to disk?

Comment: Also, no support for rar's?

Comment: For RAR you could use [Raroscope](http://code.google.com/p/raroscope/) or google for another Java library. I have mentioned Apache Commons Compress as it is the most complete Java compress library as far as I know.